# issue converting code from java 7 to java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to code the below snippet in **Java 8** -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the policy amount: ");
long amount = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the interest: ");
int interest = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the number of years: ");
int years = sc.nextInt();
sc.close();

for (int i = 1; i <= years; i++) {
    result = nextYear + amount;
    calculateInterest = result * interest / 100;
    nextYear = result + calculateInterest;
}
return nextYear;
```

I need the **nextYear** value so, have tried like below using  **IntStream**

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, years);

    intStream.forEach(num -> {
        result = nextYear + amount;
        calculateInterest = result * interest / 100;
        nextYear = result + calculateInterest;
    });
```

but, not sure how to return the **nextYear** value. How to handle this or is there any other way to do this. kindly suggest. Thank you.

Comment: why do you need a for loop at all? There must surley be a formula for interest calculation.

Comment: are you trying to calculate [compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest)?

Comment: Just in case if it is not about interest calculation, In general how can we do it? Kindly help.

Comment: *Usually* it'd be a reduce operation. But also *usually* you don't reduce when you just have a loop but when you intend to base the result on the contents of the stream.

Comment: Java 8 (even 16) still allows `for` loops... nothing wrong with them. I would only use `streams` if the code can be better *expressed* with `streams` (or for fun/testing) - very opinion-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your result is just repeatedly applying the body of the loop, the way to get that through the stream API is through the [`.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#iterate-long-java.util.function.LongUnaryOperator-) static method that allows you to generate a stream similarly formed of a repeat application of a function.

If we take the body of the loop and transform it, we get:

```
return LongStream.iterate(0, nextYear -> {
    long result = nextYear + amount;
    long calculateInterest = result * interest / 100;

    return result + calculateInterest;
})
.skip(years)
.findFirst()
.getAsLong();
```

Using some arithmetic, we can simplify the body of the lambda function. By inlining `result` and `calculateInterest` we get to just one line:

```
nextYear -> {
    return (nextYear + amount) + (nextYear + amount) * interest / 100;
}
```

By eliminating the body and refactoring the equation via grouping we get

```
nextYear -> ((nextYear + amount) * (100 + interest)) / 100
```

The final transormation therefore looks like this:

```
return LongStream.iterate(0, 
    nextYear -> ((nextYear + amount) * (100 + interest)) / 100
)
.skip(years)
.findFirst()
.getAsLong();
```

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you might want to use `reduce` with the default value as `0`. The `BinaryOperator`'s `left` would be that periodically updated value while the `right` value remains unused (it represents years - `i` or `num` in your snippets).

```
double nextYear = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, years)
        .mapToDouble(i -> (double) i)
        .reduce(0.0, (left, right) -> left + amount + ((left + amount) * interest / 100));
```

.. or more readable:

```
double nextYear = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, years)
        .mapToDouble(i -> (double) i)
        .reduce(0.0, (left, right) -> {
                double result = left + amount;
                return result + ((result) * interest / 100);
        });
```

**Note:** I am quite confused of the types of your `nextYear`, `result` and `calculateInterest` variables. You might want to change `mapToDouble` or the used types on the snippets above.

**Note 2:** However, as already said, for-loop was available before Java 8 and is available even after Java 8, so there is no reason to stop using it.

**Note 3:** Are you sure the calculation is correct?

Comment: You don't need to cast to `double` i.e. you can write `i -> (double) i` as `i -> i`.

Comment: Thank you, that's a great explanation.